# Android use Data Binding Library with CursorAdapter

Tags: android-cursoradapter, android-databinding

I want to use the Android Data Binding Library with a `ListView` populated by a custom `CursorAdapter`, but I can't figure out how to get it work. I seems such a simple thing to achieve.

This is what I have now:

```
public class PlayCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private List<Play> mPlays;

    PlayCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        mPlays = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        ListItemPlayBinding binding = ListItemPlayBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false);
        Play play = new Play();
        binding.setPlay(play);
        mPlays.add(play);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        int timeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PlayEntry.COLUMN_TIME);
        ...

        long time = cursor.getLong(timeIndex);
        ...

        Play play = mPlays.get(cursor.getPosition());

        play.setTime(time);
        ...
    }
}
```

**Current behaviour:** 
When I run this code and I scroll down in the list I get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on the **mPlays** list.

**Desired behaviour:** 
I want to populate a `ListView` with data from a `ContentProvider` using the Data Binding Library and a `CursorAdapter`. Is it even possible to use the Data Binding Library with a `CursorAdapter`? Or do you recommend to always use a `RecyclerView` and a `RecyclerView.Adapter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to avoid the problem by eliminating the mPlays list:

```
public class PlayCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    PlayCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        ListItemPlayBinding binding = ListItemPlayBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false);
        Play play = new Play();
        binding.setPlay(play);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        int timeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PlayEntry.COLUMN_TIME);
        ...

        long time = cursor.getLong(timeIndex);
        ...
        ListItemPlayBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.getBinding(view);
        Play play = binding.getPlay();

        play.setTime(time);
        ...
    }
}
```

This assumes you don't just want to instantiate a new Play each time you bindView().

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked. I was looking for the `DataBindingUtil.getBinding(view)` part. Do you recommend using a `RecyvlerView.Adapter` instead of a `CursorAdapter` or is it overkill for this situation? I read your post on Medium about using a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: RecyclerView is a newer widget that handles most of the use cases for ListView and has some additional functionality. You'll also get stability between versions of Android because it is entirely within the support library. So, I'd say that it is worth looking into RecyclerView for future layouts. That said, there's really no reason to change when something is working well for you.